# Hadoop/Hive - Split an array that consist of dictionaries into multiple rows

Tags: sql, hive

so I am trying to split an array that consists of dictionaries into multiple rows.  I tried many times and the closest thing that I got is to use the "Lateral view" with "explode" and "split".  However, I got an error saying that the in order to use "split", the argument needs to be string type while mine is an array that consists of dictionaries.  Here is what I have:

```
%sql
SELECT userId, recommendations
FROM user_rec
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(recommendations, ',')) AS movies
WHERE user_rec.userId = 575
```

The first picture below is how the picture looks like and the second picture is what I want.  Please send some help!  Thank you!!

[image: How the table looks like]
[image: What I want]

Comment: @ErisconLi, one request, please dont put image screenshots in the question/body, instead of add the data in text, it will be useful for mock the scenario in our local VMs and provide solutions easily. If you can please update the question with text tables data. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split the `array`. `explode` works on `array` and `map` data types.

```
SELECT userId, recommendations, tbl.movies
FROM user_rec
LATERAL VIEW explode(recommendations) tbl as movies
WHERE user_rec.userId = 575
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Vamsi!  Can you please tell me why I need to add 'tbl' after explode()?  I came across the Hive document and notice that one of the examples added 'adtable' instead of "tbl", so I am kinda confused by it.

Comment: it is a table alias reference, which can be anything you like (other than a reserved keyword).

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!